# Trying to create basic blog posts in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, umbraco, blogs, umbraco7

I've been trying for hours now to add blog posts into our site through the Umbraco back office. It feels so unintuitive how everything works and I'm beginning to get very frustrated, here's what I'm trying to do/have done:

- I create a document type, "BlogPost", it contains data that can be entered in a content node relating to the blog post, description, title, etc.
- I create a document type, "BlogPage", as a document type to be used as a root content node, which will hold all the BlogPost content nodes, that way I can simply loop through them and render each one on our site
- I go to create the BlogPost content node, and it assigns it an url of "/", which simply redirects to the home page

What I don't understand is how am I supposed to just get data that was entered in Umbraco for my view? We have an extremely stylized theme for our site, so I can't use things like Articulate, and I shouldn't have to, all I want to do is store a collection of blog posts together, pull that data from Umbraco, and load it into an ASP.NET view, but there is absolutely zero documentation or examples of how to do this online, I would be incredibly grateful if someone could point me in the right direction on how I should go about doing what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are developing a blog section on an existing website. First thing to do is inderdaad create a new documenttype for the blogpost itself and add a documenttype for the container of blogposts.

Did you create new templates for these documenttypes? You can find some documentation on templates [here](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/design/templates/)
Inside the template you'll want to query data from Umbraco. Information about querying data is available [here](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Design/Rendering-Content/)

Next up is adding the newly created templates to the documenttypes and you're ready to create your content.

Make sure that for the content you create the template is set (see Properties tab), here you can also see the url Umbraco created for the content.

Did you start the Umbraco website from scratch or are you developing on an existing website? Because a blogpost should not redirect to / by default, unless it's the root node of your website. This sounds like custom functiality. Maybe a rewrite or error handling module?

Edit: Also some information on how to get started with templating in Umbraco is available [here](http://umbraco.tv/videos/umbraco-v7/implementor/)

Comment: I will take a look at those links and get back with you Monday. To clarify yes, you've nailed on the head what I'm trying to do, except I don't want Umbraco to do anything in terms of laying out the page, I want it to just give me the data and that's all so that we can keep the custom look of our site without rebuilding it in Umbraco. To clarify on your other question, this site is an existing site, however I rebuilt it piece by piece in a fresh Umbraco project and redid the routing, bundling, etc. Thanks for the feedback, I'll go ahead and up vote this now, and accept later when I try it out.